# Different layouts - bad for SEO

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, seo

At the bottom of my web page, I've got a list of countries of 20 countries (generated so it changes everyday). According to the display type, I'm going to have 4, 3 or 2 columns. A PHP script generates the output for the 3 display types.

I guess this is very bad in terms of SEO and repetition is never a good idea anyway (more code to load, etc.). I'm quite new to bootstrap. Would there be a better way to do that ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="visible-lg visible-md">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a></li>
                <li><a href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li>
                <li><a href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a></li>
                <li><a href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a></li>
                <li><a href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a></li>
                <li><a href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a></li>
                <li><a href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a></li>
                <li><a href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a></li>
                <li><a href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a></li>
                <li><a href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a></li>
                <li><a href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a></li>
                <li><a href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a></li>
                <li><a href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a></li>
                <li><a href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a></li>
                <li><a href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="visible-sm">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a></li>
                <li><a href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li>
                <li><a href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a></li>
                <li><a href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a></li>
                <li><a href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a></li>
                <li><a href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a></li>
                <li><a href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a></li>
                <li><a href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a></li>
                <li><a href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a></li>
                <li><a href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a></li>
                <li><a href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a></li>
                <li><a href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a></li>
                <li><a href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a></li>
                <li><a href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a></li>
                <li><a href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a></li>
                <li><a href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a></li>
                <li><a href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li>
                <li><a href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a></li>
                <li><a href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a></li>
                <li><a href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a></li>
                <li><a href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a></li>
                <li><a href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a></li>
                <li><a href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a></li>
                <li><a href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a></li>
                <li><a href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a></li>
                <li><a href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a></li>
                <li><a href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a></li>
                <li><a href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a></li>
                <li><a href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a></li>
                <li><a href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a></li>
                <li><a href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a></li>
                <li><a href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a></li>
                <li><a href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a></li>
                <li><a href="United-States/"><img src="/img/flags/United-States.png"/>United States</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: lg&md]
[image: sm]
[image: xs]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It is both about bootstrap and about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid seo problems, you can fix your problem like this:

1. Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/hCN2j/)
2. Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/hCN2j/embedded/result/)

---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">      
        <a href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a>
    </div>             
</div>
```

No repetive content, and you should replace the ul with a standard bootstrap div.

If you want to have a simplified version that works, you can remove all the `div`'s and move the class from the `div` to the `<a>` and your code will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a>
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a>         
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a>
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a>
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a>
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a>    
    <a class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a>               
</div>
```

1. Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Qs2rj/)
2. Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Qs2rj/embedded/result/)

If you want this to be responsive, seo friendly and keep the alphabetical order, all that i think at in this moment in javascript.

```
var xs = '<a class="col-xs-6" href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li><a class="col-xs-6" href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="United-States/"><img src="/img/flags/United-States.png"/>United States</a><a class="col-xs-6" href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a>';

var sm = '<a class="col-sm-4" href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li><a class="col-sm-4" href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a><a class="col-sm-4" href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a>';

var md = '<a class="col-md-3" href="Argentina/"><img src="/img/flags/Argentina.png"/>Argentina</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Czech-Republic/"><img src="/img/flags/Czech-Republic.png"/>Czech Republic</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Italy/"><img src="/img/flags/Italy.png"/>Italy</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Spain/"><img src="/img/flags/Spain.png"/>Spain</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Australia/"><img src="/img/flags/Australia.png"/>Australia</a></li><a class="col-md-3" href="Denmark/"><img src="/img/flags/Denmark.png"/>Denmark</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Mexico/"><img src="/img/flags/Mexico.png"/>Mexico</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Sweden/"><img src="/img/flags/Sweden.png"/>Sweden</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Austria/"><img src="/img/flags/Austria.png"/>Austria</a><a class="col-md-3" href="France/"><img src="/img/flags/France.png"/>France</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Netherlands/"><img src="/img/flags/Netherlands.png"/>Netherlands</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Switzerland/"><img src="/img/flags/Switzerland.png"/>Switzerland</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Belgium/"><img src="/img/flags/Belgium.png"/>Belgium</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Germany/"><img src="/img/flags/Germany.png"/>Germany</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Norway/"><img src="/img/flags/Norway.png"/>Norway</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Turkey/"><img src="/img/flags/Turkey.png"/>Turkey</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Canada/"><img src="/img/flags/Canada.png"/>Canada</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Ireland/"><img src="/img/flags/Ireland.png"/>Ireland</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Poland/"><img src="/img/flags/Poland.png"/>Poland</a><a class="col-md-3" href="United-Arab-Emirates/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Arab-Emirates.png"/>United Arab Emirates</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Colombia/"><img src="/img/flags/Colombia.png"/>Colombia</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Israel/"><img src="/img/flags/Israel.png"/>Israel</a><a class="col-md-3" href="Portugal/"><img src="/img/flags/Portugal.png"/>Portugal</a><a class="col-md-3" href="United-Kingdom/"><img src="/img/flags/United-Kingdom.png"/>United Kingdom</a>';

var device = '';

function updateFlags(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if (device != 'xs') $('.row').html(xs);
        device = 'xs';
    }

    if ($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() < 992) {
        if (device != 'sm') $('.row').html(sm);
        device = 'sm';
    }

    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        if (device != 'md') $('.row').html(md);
        device = 'md';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    updateFlags();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateFlags();    
    });
});
```

1. Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/HBELv/)
2. Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/HBELv/embedded/result/)

Comment: Wouhou. Nice one. I thought about it but dismissed it because of heavy class usage. Only concern is that in my example, countries are ordered by columns and not by rows (which, I think, is easier to read by humans).

Comment: To be honest, classes didin't represented to me a big problem because as far as i know does not affect the SEO. What i didin't like more was the big amount of div's present in the code, but i removed them and updated the code. I've moved the classes from div to the anch and removed all the divs. This classes are very pressent in every bootstrap template. Either you use this classes, either you will use percent like width = "50%" (as for responsive design is required) is the same thing. But i still think that classes look better. Check the code above, mabey you like that better.

Comment: Sure, smaller is better. But I still don't see how to have columns ordered in the original way (alphabetical order in columns instead of rows). In your example Argentina is left to Australia instead of being above Australia).

Comment: Ah, now i understand. I will think at a solution for this.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. It's the best i can do right now.

Comment: Looks perfect to me. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Generally the concern about duplication applies to *content* rather than navigation. Google will most likely detect that the text is within links and therefore part of the navigation rather than something which should be treated as "content".

Plenty of sites have a footer navigation bar or sitemap, and in some regards it can be *good* for SEO to have a very clear navigation path around your site (by having a sitemap in the footer like this).

Assuming each of those pages is legitimate and doesn't have duplicate content, I wouldn't be concerned.